# self.delegate respondsToSelector: ... does not compile

Tags: xcode, ios5

I've implemented a protocol with an optional method and in the calling method I want to send `respondsToSelector:` to `self.delegate` before I send the message, but that does not compile. The fail message is:

*No Known instance method for selector 'respondsToSelector'*.

As a work-around, I "sanitized" the delegate as shown below, which compiles...

```
//MyClass.h:

@class MyClass;

@Protocol MyClassDelegate
- (void)myClass:(MyClass *)sender willDoSomething:(BOOL)animated;
@end

@interface MyClass : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyClassDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

and

```
//MyClass.m:

...
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
...

id sanitizedDelegate = self.delegate; //Hmmmm... why does this work?

if ([sanitizedDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myClass:willDoSomething:)]) {
    [self.delegate myClass:self willDoSomething:animated];
}
```

.

I checked a number of posts including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3697058/1074338) but it does not answer the compilation fail issue.

Also, alternative accessors do not work...

```
[self delegate]
//or
_delegate
```

Has anyone seen this or can advise a better way of handling?

IOS 5.0:(9A334), Xcode 4.2.1 (4D502)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`-respondsToSelector:` is a method on NSObject. Either assume that your `id` delegate is in fact an NSObject, and cast it:

`[(NSObject*)self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myClass:willDoSomething:)]`

Or, better, make your delegate explicitly an NSObject:

`@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject<MyClassDelegate>* delegate;`

Or make the protocol be a sub-protocol of NSObject:

`@protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>`

Comment: Ka-ching... I'll take door #3.

Comment: Declaring the delegate as NSObject worked, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Basically you are saying that your delegate is constrained only by your `<MyClassDelegate>` protocol so the compiler assumes that those are the only methods available. What you need to do is have the protocol extend `<NSObject>` like so:

```
@Protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myClass:(MyClass *)sender willDoSomething:(BOOL)animated;
@end
```

That way the compiler knows that any object which conforms to your protocol also conforms to the `<NSObject>` protocol which defines `respondsToSelector:`.

Comment: Yep, code completion advises the same... standard practice from now on.